# ReactJS complex (if / else if) not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I have the following conditional

```
if (
    !user.userId
    && match.path === '/login'
) {
    component = <Login/>
} else if (
    user.userId
    && !user.OTPVerified
    && !user.loginWithPassword
    && match.path === '/verify'
) {
    component = <VerifyOTP/>
} else if (
    (user.userId && user.OTPVerified) || (user.userId && user.loginWithPassword)
    && !user.profileCompleted
    && match.path === '/complete-profile'
) {
    console.log('userid', user.userId)
    console.log('otpverified', user.OTPVerified)
    console.log('loginWithPassword', user.loginWithPassword)
    console.log('profileCompleted', user.profileCompleted)
    console.log('path', match.path)
    component = <CompleteProfile/>
} else if (
    user.userId
    && !user.OTPVerified
    && user.loginWithPassword
    && user.profileCompleted
    && match.path === '/login-password'
) {
    component = <LoginWithPassword/>
} else {
    component = <Login/>
}
```

console returns

```
userid 29
otpverified true
loginWithPassword false
profileCompleted true
path /login
```

I dont get why am i still seeing CompleteProfile component

Comment: as per your output, your if hits this else if (
    (user.userId && user.OTPVerified) , what's your expected output?

Comment: @Nonik thats whats confusing, it shouldn't because yes ```(user.userId && user.OTPVerified)``` is true but ```&& !user.profileCompleted``` is also true so it should just go to else

Comment: Your && and || operators have the same precedence and therefore are checked left to right. Since `(user.userId && user.OTPVerified)` evaluates to `true` and therefore the condition of your if is `true || false && false && false`. That is logically equivalent to `true || (false && (false && false))` which evaluates to `true`

Comment: @ChadS.okay so how do i set the proper precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some parenthesis around those two expressions with the `||` between them if they should be evaluated together.

`((user.userId && user.OTPVerified) || (user.userId && user.loginWithPassword))`

This change makes your `Login` component show based on the values.

You can remove the inner ones too and the `&&` will be evaluated first.

`(user.userId && user.OTPVerified || user.userId && user.loginWithPassword)`

```
else if (
    (user.userId && user.OTPVerified || user.userId && user.loginWithPassword)
    && !user.profileCompleted
    && match.path === '/complete-profile'
)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#Operator_precedence

```
console.log((true && true) || (true && false) && false && false) //true
console.log((true && true || true && false) && false && false) // false
```

Comment: No you don't, you have them around each one, not around both.

Comment: oh, wonderful that solves the problem, thank you so much!!